# Stream analytics "Reference data feature is not supported in queries using OVER clause in TIMESTAMP BY."

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am getting exception in query before saving it in Stream analytics
"Reference data feature is not supported in queries using OVER clause in TIMESTAMP BY."

Query is

with mycte as
(Select Deviceid, * from input timestamp by [timestamp] over deviceid  PARTITION BY PartitionId)
Select * from mycte

Comment: Hi. Reference data cannot be used in queries using "TIMESTAMP BY ... OVER". You will be able to compile this query if you remove the reference data from the list of inputs for this job. We'll work on improving the experience in the future, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: We've worked around this by imputing reference data further up our pipeline, before it hits the ASA job that requires use of OVER.